# Prevent registration except through form

Tags: user-registration, spam

I have a Formidable Pro form that handles user registrations on my site. It has a CAPTCHA. Is it possible to prevent anyone from registering by other methods (e.g. wp-register.php)?

(I've tried using plugins to stop spam registrations but there was always something that didn't quite work for me. If the CAPTCHA is enough, why complicate things by adding a new plugin?)

Comment: Form for signup is isoreiki.com/account

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a good answer and slightly modified it on a [related question](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/170233/34991) . It uses htaccess, and redirects any requests to wp-login.php?action=register.

```
# BLOCK SPAM REGISTRATION REQUESTS (wp-login.php?action=register) 
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^.*(wp-login.php\?action=register).* [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://isoreiki.com/about/account
</IfModule>
```

Notes:

1. In the answer I linked to he totally blocked these requests. However I have redirected them to the Formidable Pro signup form, as you can see in the RewriteRule.
2. As far as I know, all regsitration attempts, even wp-register.php, will go through wp-login.php?action=register.
3. I have tested signup using my Formidable Form and it's still working fine. Also, wp-login.php, including lost password, is still working.