# How can I disable all client side new accounts without disabling new user accounts?

Tags: user-registration, account

I'm getting maybe 1-10 user registrations a day on my site. They all look like spam but maybe one in twenty.

I am using a plugin that integrates with my application that allows creating new user accounts so I don't need any client side pages that allow registrations. The plugin will do it.

How can I disable all client side registrations but allow my users to create new accounts through my plugin? I've listed some ideas below I've thought about.

**Theoretical Method 1:**
1. disable all new account creation using options on WordPress settings page
2. allow new accounts through the plugin. it calls standard methods wp_create_user()

- the problem with that is will wp_create_user() work if account creation is turned off in WordPress?
- if the api call still works will the new email account message be sent and then will the confirm email account activation link still work?

**Theoretical Method 2:**
1. Delete the wp-register.php page?

- this may prevent the page from loading but my guess is that spam bots are posting to wp-login.php which I do not want to delete.
- [apparently](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/170233/29247) there are three places where a visitor can register wp-login.php?action=register, wp-includes/wp-register.php and /wp-register.php.

Setting up Method 1 is possible but a lot of work with a lot of questions if I run into road blocks.

FYI I'm running a multiuser [WPMU](https://codex.wordpress.org/WPMU) Network site.

Comment: When you say you're running WPMU, do you mean plugins from https://premium.wpmudev.org or do you mean multisite?

Comment: I'm running a network site. I'm guessing no one calls it WPMU anymore?

Comment: WPMU and multisite aren't quite the same thing, even though multisite is based on WPMU the distinction is important ( one implies you're still using a fork of WP 3.0, the other implies a standard WordPress install )

Comment: e.g. [WPMU](https://codex.wordpress.org/WPMU) vs [multisite](https://codex.wordpress.org/Create_A_Network). If you're using WPMU I strongly advise you upgrade to a modern version of WordPress

Comment: I'm using multisite.